# Paradox or Error: On the inclusion of dense subspaces into Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

the following observations are very simple, but I suppose they contain an error, which I haven't been able to find it so far. Maybe somebody can help how to fix it:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $U$ be a dense subspace. *Assume* we can equip $U$ with another Hilbert space norm by itself. We denote this space by $\mathcal U$, to avoid misunderstandings.

We then have the linear inclusion $ i : \mathcal U \rightarrow H$ with image dense in $H$. *Assume* furthermore, $i$ is bounded.

Let us now inspect the dual arrow, which acts on the topological dual spaces:
    $i^\ast : H^\ast \rightarrow \mathcal U^\ast, \;\; w( \cdot) \mapsto w( i \cdot )$

As $i$ is a bounded injection, $i^\ast$ is now a bounded surjection. What is the kernel of $i^\ast$? We have

$\ker i^\ast = \{ w \in H^\ast : w(x) = 0, x \in \operatorname{Im} i \}$

But then $\ker i^\ast = (\operatorname{Im} i)^\perp = U^\perp = H^\perp = \{0\}$, so $i^\ast$ is injective. Hence it is an isomorphism.

**Strange:** But if we dualize $i^\ast$ again, we then see $i$ is an isomorphism, too.

Furthermore, as $H$ and $\mathcal U$ are Hilbert spaces, we are given (isometric) isomorphisms $H \simeq H^\ast$, $\mathcal U \simeq \mathcal U^\ast$. We can compose these morphisms.

**Strange:** We obtain $\mathcal U \simeq H$, where the injection is in fact an isomorphism.

So this eventually means, if we equip any dense subspace of a Hilbert space with a stronger topology, then the injection $i$ as above is an isomorphism.

This seems paradoxical, and I suppose there is an error in the above. For example, this implies the injection $H^1(\mathbb R) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb R)$ is an isomorphism.

So, can anybody please either: (a) Point out where I have been wrong (b) Point out how to interpret this paradox?

Comment: Can you explain why $i^{\ast}$ is surjective?

Comment: @Qiaochu: That's exactly the point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error lies in "As $i$ is a bounded injection, $i^{\ast}$ is a bounded surjection". In fact, the range of $i$ is closed in $H$ if and only if the range of $i^{\ast}$ is closed in $U^{\ast}$ by the [closed range theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_range_theorem).

However, in the present situation, we need not use this rather difficult result (which is true for all Banach spaces) but it's more an exercise in the yoga of orthogonal complements.

---

**Added Later**

As I failed to mention (and Nate was kind enough to point out in his answer), the image of $i^{\ast}$ is dense of course. This is implicit in my yoga exercise above.

To see why $i^{\ast}$ need not be surjective, let me treat the concrete situation of the question by exhibiting an explicit example of a functional on $H^1$ which is not in the image of $i^{\ast}$.

Recall the following facts: The Sobolev space $H^1[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$ (since it contains the smooth functions) and consists of *continuous functions*. In fact, there is an inclusion  $H^1[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ which is compact (hence continuous) by one of the standard compactness theorems (whose exact name I tend to forget), when the former is equipped with its Sobolev norm and the latter is equipped with the sup norm.

Therefore it makes sense to define the evaluation functional $\phi(f) = f(p)$ for $f \in H^1$ and $p \in [0,1]$ and $\phi$ is continuous with respect to the Sobolev norm.

On the other hand, $\phi$ is not continuous with respect to the $L^2$-norm, as can be seen by choosing an appropriate sequence of smooth bump functions such that $\|f_n\|_2 \to 0$ and $\phi(f_n) = f_n (p) \to \infty$.

This means that $\phi$ cannot be in the image of $i^{\ast}$ (which is simply the restriction of functionals on $L^2$ to $H^1$ via $i$), and hence $i^{\ast}$ fails to be surjective.

Comment: I'm feeling slow today. Can you explain why $i^{\ast}$ is _not_ surjective by Hahn-Banach?

Comment: @Qiaochu: I'm not quite sure how you want to apply Hahn-Banach.

Comment: @Buehler: ok, if we identify $H$ with its dual, we then have $\{0\} = \ker i = (\operatorname{Im}i^\ast)^\perp$, so the image is still dense at least, isn't it?

Comment: @Martin: Yes this is correct, and I think this also answers the question Qiaochu asked. (meta: I prefer to be called Theo)

Comment: @Theo: I want to push forward a continuous linear functional on $\mathcal{U}$ to a linear functional on its image in $H$. Is it false that the resulting linear functional will always be continuous?

Comment: @Qiaochu: yes this is false. An example that illustrates well what can go wrong is the following: Thinking of $U = H^1(0,1) \subset H = L^2[0,1]$ we have that $U$ consists of continuous functions (and the inclusion $U \subset C([0,1])$ is continuous from the Sobolev norm to the sup-norm). So we can define a continuous linear functional on $U$ by evaluating at $1/2$, say. However, there is no way we can extend this to a continuous linear functional on all $L^2$ which would be possible (even uniquely) if your construction worked.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Reading what I wrote in my last comment again, I think I didn't make myself very clear. Evaluation at a point gives a continuous functional on $C[0,1]$ which is continuous with respect to the sup-norm, but discontinuous with respect to the $L^2$-norm. Restricting this functional to the Sobolev space $H^1$ we still get a continuous functional (wrt Sobolev norm) but discontinuous wrt $L^2$. The first claim follows from continuity of the inclusion $H^1 \subset C$ and the latter by choosing smooth bump functions whose support concentrates towards $p$ but whose values at $p$ explode.

Comment: @Theo: thanks. I figured that was the case but didn't know a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth mentioning that although, as Theo points out, $i^*$ need not be surjective, it is close: under these assumptions, $i^*$ has dense image.  Proving this is a nice short exercise.

Comment: Comment added for other people reading: in the Banach space setting, the adjoint of a linear injection with dense range will have weak-star-dense range, but might not have norm-dense range. The inclusion $\ell^1\to\ell^2$ is an example.